# VSCODE run in containers stuck for a very long time

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When I used "Remote - Containers" extension of VS Code to setup a development environment, it stuck in one of the step for 661 seconds. What's the purpose of this step? Is there any way to boost this step?

Below is part of the container log shown in VS Code, we can see a long time interval from 27646 ms to 689201 ms, which took 86.9% of all start time.

[image]

The content of .devcontainer/devcontainer.json is

[image]

The content of .devcontainer/Dockerfile is

[image]

Step to reproduce

1. Open an folder in VS Code
2. Remote-Containers: Add Development Container Configuration Files

   - From a predefined container configuration definition
   - Alpine
   - 3.14
3. Remote-Containers: Reopen in Container

By the way, the folder I opened is a remote folder in an Linux server, with docker installed.

After stuck for a while, the folder was successfully opened, but I really wonder how to boost it, otherwise it's hard to use.

Comment: I used the similar "Attach to container..." and it took also like something around 5 minutes on this step. I mean "attach" means the container already exists, so it can't be that it's trying to fire up a container from scratch or anything, so it's taking its time doing something else ‍♂️. It worked in the end though, but if I have to wait 5 minutes every time opening this workspace, hmmm.... yes, inconvenient.